# JQuery - Prevent browsers to scroll up after remove row (TR)

Tags: jquery

I have a table with rows toward the bottom of the page. I have a Jquery script below which removes the row when user clicks on the "Delete" link in the row, and it works fine. However, every time the row gets deleted, the browser keep scroll up top, then I have to scroll it down to delete another row.

Is there a way to prevent the browsers from scroll up after the table row deleted?

This is my JQuery for deleting row:

```
jQuery.fn.removeRow = function()
    {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        $(row).remove();
    }
```

This is the Delete link within the cell (TR/TD).

```
<a href="#" onClick="$(this).removeRow();">Delete</a>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Whoever voted my post (-) is not a nice person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `event.preventDefault()` in the click event.

For a native javascript example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault

For example if using jQuery, it passes the `event` to the function you define:

```
$('.delete-row').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // remove the row code goes here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  My function doesn't have event.  I tried $(this).preventDefault(); but it doesn't work. I am new to Jquery, please advise.

Comment: Updated my answer with a jquery demo. You can adapt this to your own code.

Comment: @hellion3, I tried to modify the code, but no luck.  I must have done something wrong. I have updated the post with the Delete link.  Please see if you can help with the demo.  thanks.

Comment: Give your link a class instead (like `class="delete-row"`) and then use the code I gave you. That attaches the click event without you needing to embed javascript in html with the `onclick`

Comment: I have the link a class like you said ( <a href="#" class="delete-row">Delete</a> ) and used your code, but somehow it is not working. I will keep playing with it.  Thank you for helping.

Comment: I think I know that problem why it is not working. So, I have the default row# 1. User clicks on Add Row button, it adds a new row, but copy ALL ELEMENTS (including the link for DELETE) in the 1st default row.  I used your advice by giving the link a class, only the 1st can be deleted, but not the new rows added.  I am still trying to figure out how to make all the added rows have the same class.

Comment: The issue is that `$('.delete-row')` adds a click event for all *existing* elements. You need something called a `delegated` event, which listens for existing and new elements that match. Like `$('body').on('click', '.delete-row', function(event){ // your stuff });`. `body` can be whatever the highest element is that contains this row/system of yours.

Comment: sounds complicated, but thanks for the info. Lets see if  I can figure all that out.

Comment: I took a look of your demo, but I couldn't figure out how to fix mine. Sorry. Is that OK I post my codes and you help correct it?

Comment: I can look at what you have sure

Comment: I updated with the table and the JQuery I have, please find the Delete link. Thank you so much for helping....

Comment: Try changing `$('.deleteRow').click(function () {` to `$('#tableBucket').on('click', '.deleteRow').click(function () {`

Comment: This seems to work,  **$('#tableBucket').eq(0).on('click', 'td a.deleteRow', function()** , but it is not deleting the row (TR) now. Any suggestion to find the the row and delete it?